# Have I solved this congruence correctly?

Tags: number-theory

[image]
![]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMDnZ.jpg [1]

Which can not be solved as gcd(16,22)=2, 2 does not divide 7. Hence no solutions to the congruence.

Furthermore the congruence can not be solved as 3 is not a primitive root modulo 23

Comment: What do you denote *ind* and *xind*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $o(3)$ denote the order of the number $3$ modulo $23$. We know that $o(3)|22$, hence $o(3)\in\{1,2,11,22\}$ but obviously we have $o(3)\neq1,2$. Now with Euler's criterion and quadratic reciprocity we have
$$
3^{11}\equiv\left(\frac3{11}\right)\equiv-\left(\frac{11}3\right)\equiv-\left(\frac23\right)\equiv1\pmod{23}
$$
Hence $o(3)=11$

Now observe that every two solutions to the equation $3^x\equiv{17}\pmod{11}$ are congruent modulo $11$, so you must find one solution to find all. But in this case there is no solution and for this you should exam $x$'s in a complete set of residues modulo $11$...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solutions consists in observing that $3$  has order $11$ modulo 23, while $17$ has order $22$ so that, by Lagrange's theorem,  $17$ can't lie in the subgroup generated by $3$.